# Mobile Design CSS?

Tags: mobile

I am attempting to make my first mobile website by just using a different style sheet but I'm noticing it is more complicated than I expected. Everything is really different when I test both my iPhone 4S and my wife's android. What do I need to use to make it like Facebook's mobile site? Where you can't zoom in or out and it all just fits on your screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make sure your page doesn't need to be zoomed, add the following `meta` tag in your HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport"
 content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0;
 maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0"></meta>
```

It does the following:

- Width of the viewport is scaled to your device's width (`width=device-width`)
- Initial and maximum scales are set to `1.0`
- User scaling (zooming) is disabled

If you are looking for methods to allow your website to smoothly work for mobile devices, tablets as well as desktop devices, the keyword is **responsive design** (or responsive web design). Read [this article on A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/) to get started. Also for a hugely popular (very Facebook-like) responsive layout, see [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). For highly mobile optimized UI components, I really recommend taking a look at [jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Apple's documentation in the [Safari Developer Library](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html). Basically you need to use `meta` tags to tell the browser your website is mobile capable. You can customize the pinch zoom style and stuff using these tags too.

Specifically, you want

```
<meta content='width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;' name='viewport' />
```

Should probably note that some of the things described in the Safari Developer Library will only work on iOS devices. The code above should work on Android as well as iOS, though.